# Realtime WebSocket stream to RTSP

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, rtsp

I've been looking for days a solution to convert a video stream (video/webcam) from a web browser to a backend RTSP stream.
All I could find was backwards, from RTSP to WebSockets (to display in a web page).
I want the user to choose from a web browser client, a video or webcam locally and then send it to a nodejs server.
Opening a webcam and send the chunks via websockets, seems easy, but how to "convert" these chunks of video to a RTSP server, and then connect via VLC to see the stream ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ffmpeg is great tool to convert media data.

Comment: Dear Marc, yes. Thank you. But as far as I know, it does not handle websockets.

Comment: right, ffmpeg cant handle websockets. But you can write a node.js websocket server, which spawns a ffmpeg child process that does the video processing.

Comment: Marc, now that you threw a light over my problem, this makes so much sense!
Thank you so much!
I will research here, but would you have any code to get me started ?
Anyways this seems to be the right answer!!!

Comment: Suits not 100% your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086772/5781499 Implement a WebSocket server, create of the ws connection a stream (the `ws` module on npm can do both) pipe that stream into ffmepg stdin. Let me know if you need help or ask a seperate question an mention me in the comments.

Comment: Marc, in the words of Tina Turner, you're simply the best!!
Can't thank you enough for your support!
I am going to push myself to learn this and share with the community!
I will let you know if I get stuck on some part of the code!

Thaanks once again!

Comment: Your welcome. Let me know if/how i can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239584/discussion-between-mrax-and-marc).

Comment: Marc, could you please take a look at the chat ? Thank you.